# I am adding crmButton in the template for EventInfo.tpl , how can I add drupal callback function and makesure it does not breaks as is the case here?

Tags: drupal, smarty, button

[image]

```
{crmButton p='drupal/event-workflow/$uid/$gid' q="action=browse&reset=1&gid=$gid" icon="th-list"}{ts}Request for Approval{/ts}{/crmButton}
```

Where I have defined $uid and $gid variables in smarty template,
How can I fix the the Unable to reach the server error, I checked the logs but there is no error with regards to this request,so I guess its something to do with button's **q and p attributes**

Comment: Make sure $uid and $gid are properly evaluated in the above line. For eg, I see the `p` assignment is done in single quotes. Try changing it to use double quote. eg `p="drupal/event-workflow/$uid/$gid"`

Comment: Yes they are correct

Comment: Opening it on new tab works

Comment: Try adding `class="action-item"` attribute to the crmButton.

Comment: ok, what does that do? can you elaborate it in an answer, what can we do to open it in a new tab? incase it does not help ? @jitendra-fuzion

Comment: Can you please add the requirement, i guess you want to change form action based the user clicks on the button. Isn't?

Comment: Hi @PradeepNayak, I want to add create new drupal node programmatically once user clicks on the button

Comment: to do that in the p , I am adding p="drupal/event-workflow/110/10 where 110 is coming from $gid and 10 is coming from $uid so its actually "drupal/event-workflow/$gid/$uid ,then I add hook_menu where I define this url drupal/event-workflow/110/10 but when i click on civicrm button it gives the error shown in the screenshot above @PradeepNayak

Comment: Hi @jitendra-fuzion,can you explain on how I can add the class, I tried adding clas="action-item" as seen here:            {crmButton p="event-workflow/approve/$eventID/$uid" q="reset=1&action=update&id=$eventID&component=event" icon="th-list" class="action-item" }{ts} Approve{/ts}{/crmButton}

Comment: I added as shown in the above comment @jitendra-fuzion, but it does not help,looking forward for your feedback,thanks!